# Why no dedicated support for many platforms?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why no dedicated support for many platforms?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196310/why-no-dedicated-support-for-many-platforms?/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best answer you can get for that kind of question:

Because someone needs to do that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10